# How do I animate the move a UILabel with auto layout constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, cgaffinetransform, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to move a UILabel to the left and animate the movement. The UILabel is created from a storyboard, and has the following constraints:

[image]

But if I try to make the trailing space constant equal to say, 150 instead of 20 to move it to the left, it bounces to the left weirdly for a second then comes back to the middle. So I lowered the priority of the left leading constraint to 900, but the same thing still happened.

So I tried:

```
self.textToReadLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-500.0, 0.0);
```

Which moves it, but if I use an animation with it it slides off screen, slides back on and then rests in the place it should... after all those theatrics.

How exactly would I achieve this?

#### Entirety of what happens when I tap the button to move the label:

```
        self.textHorizontalPlacementConstraint.constant = 150.0;
        self.textHorizontalPlacementConstraint2.constant = -110.0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];

        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        animation.duration = 0.5;
        animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        [self.textToReadLabel.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];

        // Change the text
        self.textToReadLabel.text = @"text";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a layout change animated you need to change the `constant` in your `NSLayoutConstraint` and then call:

```
    self.textHorizontalPlacementConstraint.constant = 150.0;
    self.textHorizontalPlacementConstraint2.constant = -110.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

Also make sure you're constraints are consistent. So if you increase the trailingSpace also reduce the leadingSpace.

Comment: As I said, I tried changing the constant (including calling layoutIfNeeded). I tried changing both of them, but the same thing happened. It flies off screen for a second then reappears.

Comment: I added the code, but it doesn't seem particularly helpful. Is there more that I could add?

Comment: I tried that, but it still has the same effect. Here's a video of what I'm talking about, maybe it will help: http://cl.ly/3l2E401N3Q3h EDIT: And I added literally all the code I thought may be relevant.